# justInTimeInstall not working for MessageExtension app in Meetings on Desktop Teams

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I have a message extension only app that initiates a sequence of Task Modules during a Teams Meeting. The app manifest is side-loaded by a Tenant Administrator. During the meeting, the host of the meeting (also the Tenant Administrator) chooses the message extension from the chat entry field and executes the command.

The first step in the sequence is to add our bot to the meeting chat so that our app can be a full participant in the meeting. Our server gets the event to invoke our message extension and returns a response that has an action for 'justInTimeInstall'.

When the host clicks on the button to execute the justInTimeInstall, we get an error message that fills the body of the task module that says : Unable to reach app. Please try again.

In the Dev Tools console log, I see an error reported:

```
?agent=electron&vers…600&ring=ring3_6:69
CDL: {
  "errorCode":"Error",
  "requestId":"m-178",
  "hostRendererId":"5e3ce6c0-2b1f-4285-8d4b-75ee78787346","
  component":"RequestHandler",
  "requestWindowId":"7a96f559-7ed3-48ba-a35d-1914afeff2a8",
  "operationType":"mutation",
  "operationName":"installApp",
  "message":"error while processing m-178: {
    \"name\":\"Error\",
    \"message\":\"Unexpected error value: {
      message: \\\"getGroupChatAppDefinition - No registeredApp found with
        appId (bda89c27-e179-45f8-9eee-3550a2691be5) for
        chat (19:meeting_OTQ5Njg0YzktNmM0OC00ZGNhLTg3NWMtYjE2NWQzZmJjZDk1@thread.v2),
      callerContext: (cdl)\\\",
      status: \\\"NotFound\\\"
    }\",
    \"stack\":[]
  } (reason: undefined)"
}
console.error   @   ?agent=electron&vers…600&ring=ring3_6:69
sendToConsoleAndDiagnosticLogs  @   main-ff5698c1ba89bafb.js:23
invoke  @   main-ff5698c1ba89bafb.js:23
error   @   main-ff5698c1ba89bafb.js:23
(anonymous) @   main-ff5698c1ba89bafb.js:23
safeWrapILoggerCall @   main-ff5698c1ba89bafb.js:23
error   @   main-ff5698c1ba89bafb.js:23
onError @   main-ff5698c1ba89bafb.js:23
setResponseAndEndScenario   @   main-ff5698c1ba89bafb.js:23
reconcileResponse   @   main-ff5698c1ba89bafb.js:23
onMessageReceived   @   main-ff5698c1ba89bafb.js:23
Vr.onResponseReceived   @   main-ff5698c1ba89bafb.js:23
(anonymous) @   main-ff5698c1ba89bafb.js:23
(anonymous) @   main-ff5698c1ba89bafb.js:36
(anonymous) @   main-ff5698c1ba89bafb.js:36
(anonymous) @   VM5:2
emit    @   VM4 sandbox_bundle.js:178
onMessage   @   VM4 sandbox_bundle.js:159
```

The ID referenced in the error does not correspond to any ID we use in our manifest or to any of the IDs in any of the conversations.

Using exactly the same setup, this step works fine if the meeting is run from a web browser. It also works if the Message Extension app is added to the chat from the Chat panel in the Desktop app's main window.

Once our bot is successfully added, we can invoke the Message Extension from the meeting chat within the meeting window without error -- we only need to add our app to the chat once.

I feel like i'm missing something obvious but I can't think of where to look for the solution.

Comment: Could you please reverify if you have used the App ID properly, because according to error it seems like there is an issue with ID itself? Try updating MS Teams app version as well, that might help.

Answer (score 1):

Above issue resolved by uploading app to Teams admin center instead of side loading. Reference related to same: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/msteams-docs/issues/6537#issuecomment-1196299673